# Rails - Join tables to sort posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app I have a table Designs which are essentially the posts. Users can like these Designs (using the [thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) gem). This table is called Votes. On user's profile pages, I'm showing all of the Designs that they have liked (or voted for). In the user model, I have a method:

```
def favorites
  Design.joins(:votes).where('voter_id = ?', self.id).where('voteable_type = ?', 'Design').where('vote = ?', true)
end
```

Then in the user's controller to call these designs I have

```
def show
  @designs = @user.favorites
end
```

This shows all of the designs they have liked, but it's in order of when the Design was created, not when the Vote was created. The Vote table has a created_at column so I know I can sort these Designs based on when they liked them.

I tried this with no luck

```
def favorites
  results = Design.joins(:votes).where('voter_id = ?', self.id).where('voteable_type = ?', 'Design').where('vote = ?', true)
  results.sort! {|t1, t2| t2.vote.created_at <=> t1.vote.created_at}
end
```

How can I sort the Designs based on when that user liked them.

the Vote table has these columns

```
vote: boolean
voteable_id: integer
voteable_type: string
voter_id: integer
created_at: date
updated_at: date
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prior answer doesn't work because scopes work at the Class level, so when you use it on a instance of User, it assumes `favorites` is a instance method or association.

What I recommend you do is use the Vote model, and reference the belongs_to Design association on Vote:

```
def show
  @votes = @user.votes.includes(:design).order(created_at: :asc)
  @designs = @votes.collect {|v| v.design }
end
```

You could feel free to move that to the `User` model in place of your `favorites` method like so:

```
def favorites
  @favorites ||= self.votes.includes(:design).order(created_at: :asc).collect {|v| v.design }
end
```

---

### UPDATE

Since you are using this `thumbs_up` gem, the following will work:

In Action

```
def show
  @designs = @user.votes.where(voteable_type: 'Design').order(created_at: :asc).collect {|v| v.voteable}
end
```

Or Method

```
def favorites
  @favorites ||= self.votes.where(voteable_type: 'Design').order(created_at: :asc).collect {|v| v.voteable}
end
```

https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up

Comment: Thanks for the reply @omarvelous. With the second method you mentioned in my `User` model, with this call in the controller: `@designs = @user.favorites`, I am receiving the error `Association named "design" was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`. The way this gem works is using a `acts_as_voteable` in the voteable model (if that's relevent information), because I'm unsure why the association wasn't found, besides to find the voteable model of the `Vote` it's stored in a string called `voteable_type`

Comment: I quickly read the plugin, you'll want to do the following, I updated in the answer above.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for taking all this time to help me out. I really appreciate it! I think you def got it right but Im getting this error involving type association. `undefined method "by_type"`...I recently read that the #type association was deprecated

Comment: Updated once more... Odd, it's still in the readme of the gem

Comment: Misread your question, you are using the https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up gem! lol ok. ENTIRELY up to you, but https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable might be more up to date, also supports Rails 4.

Comment: You are awesome!! Btw, I changed votable_type to voteable_type and same for votable. You forgot an "e" in there but this works like a charm! I have been stuck on this for so long now so I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Yea different Gems but same functionality/associations pretty much

Comment: Same! If you want to, I would update your answer to include the proper spelling in case someone with a similar question checks out this post! Thanks again so much for the help! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be able to use a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for this - I'd use a `scope` on the `user` model to communicate with the votes model from your `user` instance:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes, as :voteable
    has_many :designs, through: :votes

    scope :favorites, -> { joins(:votes).where('voter_id = ? AND votable_type = ? AND vote = ?', id, 'Design', true) }
    scope :latest, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }
    scope :latest_favorites, -> { favorites.order(created_at: :asc) }
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user.favorites.latest
@user.latest_favorites
```

Comment: Weirdly, I'm getting an `undefined method "favorites"` which has been defined in the User model

Comment: How is your `@user` instance var defined?

Comment: `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])`

Comment: find_by_username is a dynamic method and it wont work if users table doesn't have a username column or User model haven't a username attribute. Check if it returns nil.

Comment: Dynamic finders have been deprecated in Rails 4. You should be using `User.find_by(username: params[:username])`. You seem to have an attribute mismatch here though (using an id to search by username). Have you tried `User.find(params[:id])`?